# Is a second extension request for a visitor to Canada necessary if a previous request is still pending but its extension date has been reached?

Tags: canada, visa-extensions

Due to the pandemic, the processing time for visitor record (extension of stay) has increased significantly (almost 7 months currently).

If someone, with a valid Canadian temporary visitor visa, applied in August 2020 to extend their stay (authorized until August 31, 2020) in Canada and in that application indicated they plan to stay for six more months until February 28, 2021, do they need to submit a second application for extension for the period after March 1, 2021 (and does it matter if it is submitted after March 1)?

They are supposed to be legally staying in Canada under implied status during the processing of their application, but I am not certain if or how much the intended stay period in the application form matters.

(1) If they leave before a decision is made but after March 1, 2021, do they still benefit from the implied status?

(2) Will the application be "automatically" denied when it finally arrives at processing? Or would a grace period be given from the date of decision?